# "How to solve error: ';' expected in Java?"

Tags: java

I am trying to run my code line but it shows a minor error.
I also make some effort to put something like `\ ; " "` but it doesn't work.

```
public static void message() {
    System.out.println("This program surely cannot");
    System.out.println("have any \"errors")"in it");
}
```

I expect that this method can run, but it shows that:

> ```
> Error:(9, 48) java: ';' expected.
> ```

Comment: `System.out.println("have any \"errors\")\"in it");` should work, but does not make sure you get what you want as output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape all of the quotes `"` in the string with backspaces `\`:

```
public static void message() {
    System.out.println("This program surely cannot");
    System.out.println("have any \"errors\")\"in it");
}
```

Otherwise the parser sees that you've ended your string, and will break when there's some random characters after the `)` that it doesn't know how to interpret. This is simply a syntax error, and will crash when compiling.

```java
System.out.println("have any \"errors")"in it");
                                     ^^^~~~~~~~~
                                     |||    ^
                                     |||    |
                                     ||| Parser sees these as just random characters
                 String ends here____|||
                                      ||____Here should be a semicolon
                                      |
                                     println( matches this
```

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println("have any \"errors")"in it");
```

There is a syntax error: you have to escape the quotes:

```
System.out.println("have any \"errors\")\"in it");
```